# Network icon suddenly disappeared from the notification area on Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: unity, networking, icons

I am using Ubuntu 13.04 and there is problem with network icon. It suddenly hide from top-right corner of the screen and disconnect with wifi-internet . I also restart the network-manager service by using terminal like:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

But I am fail to show it again on the tray.

The output for `cat /etc/network/interfaces` is:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

I reboot my system to re-connect with the internet. This is awful and time consuming. Please if anyone know about solution, guide me how I reach to solve it.

Tkanks

Comment: May I see the output for `cat /etc/network/interfaces`?? Please edit your question and post

Comment: Have you tried to run `nm-applet`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

search for **Startup Applications** from the dash menu and do below on the dialog box which is appearing.

Simply add below details, then restart back to see whether its appearing.

[image]

Comment: I did this what you asking for but it can't happen. Now I'm shiffted on Ubuntu 13.10 but the same problem here. Any other solution???